# Convert OpenSSL public key into NSS one

Tags: cryptography, openssl, nss

How do I convert public key generated by OpenSSL into one NSS would understand? I've generated key with OpenSSL, exported it into pkcs12 format, imported it into NSS database and then extract public key with McCoy utility. And it was different to my great surprise. That is probably the matter of encoding but which one should I use?

Update: Looks like OpenSSL **contain** NSS key inside so the question is - how do I find out which part of OpenSSL key is also a NSS key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
openssl x509 -in mycert.pem -pubkey
```

does the job nicely